# css align div right with at table at 100% on right

Tags: css, html, css-float, alignment

I have a table set to 100% width.  I will add a random div with php full of ads at times. I want the ad div to be on the right and the content of the table. I want the table to be on the left but still at 100% or so it will fill all the space to the left of the ad div.

In short, so when the div is not present the table will fill 100% width.
When the div is present the div will be on the right side of the table at a set width of 300px.

Here is the style for the div

```
.ContentAds {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    clear: none;
}
```

The table is not a div but simply set to 100% width.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><p class="Title">Title</p>
    <p>This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content.. </p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does it mean `I want the ad div to be on the right and the content of the table.`? Also what do you want exactly: `table to be on the left but still at 100%` or  div to be `at a set width of 300px`

Comment: if the div is not present the table will be at 100%. If it is present then it will be on the left side at 300px and the table contents will be on the left of the div but fill the entire space. Make sense?

Comment: If table will stretch to 100% width and have the same parent with the div then there will be no place for div cause parent's width is 100% and you want 100% + 300px. but I'm sure that there is some solution you only have to clarify your task

Comment: right. what I mean by 100% at that moment is to fill the left side of the page... all of it. So maybe there is 70 percent left but I want the table to fill 100 percent of the space on the left.

Comment: Show some php. You need to toggle dynamically css-class of the table or may be id. So when you send to client html without div table will have 100% width, and when with a div, you will provide another style

Answer (score 2):

For now I can only suggest to wrap your table with a positioned div. But I can't be sure that it will be sufficient to you cause you provided rather small amount of code
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ySx3j/)

```
<div class="ad">
    advertise... advertise
    advertise... advertise
    advertise... advertise
</div>
<div class="table_wr">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="Title">Title</p>
                <p>
                    This is the content. This is the content.
                    This is the content. This is the content.
                    This is the content. This is the content.
                    This is the content. This is the content..
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}
.ad {
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #a2e89f;
}
.table_wr {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 300px;
}
```

border is set for table for you can see where table stretches

Answer (score 0):

I think this won't work unless you give the table a smaller set width when the other DIV is present then you could float it to the left too.

Perhaps you could have the table set to be 100% then when the other DIV is there you add a class onto the table which adjusts the width and floats it?